# NavMeshAgent face same direction as destination point in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding, navmesh

I have a NavMeshAgent NPC that walks correctly to its destination position. However, when it stops, it faces the walking direction, while I would like to have it turn to the same direction as the destination point, in the most natural way as my NPC is a human.

[image]

Is there a way to have the NPC, while walking to the destination point, also to set a destination rotation?

Comment: What you can do is use the LookAt Function (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) and have it look at the destination position when it start its path, like a normal person would do.

Answer (score 0):

You can set and idle animation. 
Then you can trigger a look at function with this animation

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html